# Make an own 'widget/layout' where you can put variable strings on

Tags: java, android, layout, sdk, widget

I'm new to java programming and I'm currently working on an app. I want to create something like this:  http://i40.tinypic.com/2zqu7hj.png

So a layout where I can put my own variable strings on. It needs to be a class because I need to reuse it and put not only one but more after each other. Like this: http://i39.tinypic.com/34g5wg3.png (but with other strings).

Does somebody know what I'm searching or how do I accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

What Android version are you developing for? You could use [fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html), if your platform supports them. They were added in 3.0, but there's a [compatibility library](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html) to support older versions, too. Inside the fragment, you could just programmatically create TextViews and insert them into the main view, which might be a relative layout.

Comment: Then it will work, the compatibility layer supports even lower versions. Check our the guide i linked to above, it explains everything and provides an example.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if thats what I'm looking for. What it needs to do is: 
The screens above needs to be placed on the the main menu activity, when you click on the lets say 'Preferences' menu, you go into another activity where you can set the strings, then when you click save or something and go back to the main menu it needs to update those 'string1' 'string2' etc with something that I have set in the 'Preferences' menu.